# Composition of homotopy classes

Tags: homotopy-theory

> For a map $f: X \to Y$, we let $[f]$ denote the equivalence class containing $f$, called the homotopy class of $f$. Therefore, since homotopies are compatible with composition, it follows that if $\alpha = [f] \in [Y,Z]$ and $\beta = [g]\in [X,Y]$ then $\alpha \beta = [fg] \in [X,Z]$.

I am confused by this claim, because it seems to be implying that the homotopy classes $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are homotopic, but I don't see how that is possible.

Comment: Why would it imply anything on $\alpha$ and $\beta$ ?

Comment: @CaptainLama The book cites it for the reason why.

Answer (score 2):

For me what is written is just a definition : you have $\alpha\in [Y,Z]$ and $\beta\in [X,Y]$, and you want to define $\alpha\beta$.

The first thing that comes to mind is that is $\alpha = [f]$ and $\beta = [g]$, then we define $\alpha\beta = [fg]$. But a priori this is ill-defined, you have to check that it doesn't depend on the choice of $f$ and $g$, ie that if $[f] = [f']$ and $[g] = [g']$, then $[fg] = [f'g']$. And there is a (basic) theorem that says this is true, which is referred to as "since homotopies are compatible with composition" in your text.

Comment: So the homotopy classes are homotopic?

Comment: This sentence doesn't make sense. You can't say that homotopy classes are homotopic or not. What do you mean precisely ?

Comment: I am saying that the result (theorem) in my book that says that homotopies are compatible with composition is if $f \simeq g$, which I don't see how it follows the homotopy classes are also compatible with composition by this without them being homotopic.

Comment: But $[f] = [f']$ and $[g] = [g']$ precisely means that $f\simeq f'$ and $g\simeq g'$, and the conclusion $[fg] = [f'g']$ means $fg\simeq f'g'$. Is it clearer that way ?

Comment: How does that imply $\alpha \beta = [fg]$?

Comment: Because that is the litteral definition of what it means. What does $\alpha\beta$ mean for you ?

Comment: It means the composition of homotopy classes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37976/discussion-between-user19405892-and-captain-lama).